# How to add 2 or more opencv imshow windows to appear in large single window?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to make a project which has three `imshow` windows each of different size, is there a way to make those three windows to pane or stack and display them in another window? Currently they are displayed like this[image]

How can i make a window which will contain all these windows and only the main window will have a close button and not all of them.

Comment: You could use `tkinter`.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same, but couldn't find any resources explaining how to do so.

Comment: You can use matplotlib's `subplot`. I believe there are a few examples here on Stack Overflow and it's used in the OpenCV Python tutorials ([example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d0f/tutorial_py_gradients.html)).

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: @AnnZen, i'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Use

To stack them vertically:

```
img = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=0)
```

To stack them horizontally:

```
img = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
```

Then show them using cv2.imshow

Comment: I have tried this but it is showing that windows to be concatenated must be of same size

Comment: Use cv2.resize before concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in each image and store all but the first one, `img0`, into a list, `imgs`. Iterate through each image in the `imgs` list, comparing the width of `img0` and the image of the iteration. With that we can define a pad, and update the `img0` with the image:

Lets say we have these three images:

`one.png`:

[image]

`two.png`:

[image]

`three.png`:

[image]

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread("one.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("two.png")
img3 = cv2.imread("three.png")

imgs = [img1, img2, img3]

result = imgs[0]
for img in imgs[1:]:
    w = img.shape[1] - result.shape[1]
    pad = [(0, 0), (0, abs(w)), (0, 0)]
    if w > 0:
        result = np.r_[np.pad(result, pad), img]
    else:
        result = np.r_[result, np.pad(img, pad)]

cv2.imshow("Image", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]